# Determine the GCD of all number that can be writen under the form of $p^8-1$, with $p$ prime and $p>5$

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

First of all they are all even... So it is at least $2$. But is it bigger than that? How do I find out?

Comment: None of them is prime for sure, because they are all even and larger than $2$.

Comment: Ohh yea.... well thought...

Comment: It's edited....

Comment: Factor the expression and find relatively prime divisors of each factor. If my mental math is right, the answer is $240$. I'm on mobile now, but I can write a solution when I get to my laptop.

Comment: @User8128 $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, so $p^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{32}$, you seem to have lost one factor of $2$ on the way.

Comment: Cheating a little and using Maple to factor this expression for the first few primes, reveals that the answer is a divisor of $2^5\cdot3\cdot5$. Maybe that *is* the answer? You only need to show that this is in fact a divisor in all cases prove it. The factorization $p^8-1=(p^4+1)(p^2+1)(p+1)(p-1)$ nails the factor $2^5$, at least.

Comment: Closely related, near dupe: [the question with $p^{12}-1$, and a minor additional restriction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906639/the-greatest-common-divisors-of-all-numbers-that-are-one-less-than-the-twelfth-p)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $(p,2)=1$  using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html),

for $n\ge3,\lambda(2^n)=2^{n-2}$  we have $2^{n-2}=8\iff n=5$

Again, for any prime $q,\lambda(q^m)=q^{m-1}(q-1)$

So, $q-1$  must divide $8\implies q=3,5$

Observe that $(p,3)=(p,5)=1$

For $q=3,\lambda(3^{a+1})=3^a(3-1)$ which must divide $8\implies a=0$

Can you handle $q=5?$

Answer (score 1):

We see $p^8-1 =(p^4+1)(p^4-1)=(p^4+1)(p^2+1)(p+1)(p-1)$. Each of these is divisible by $2$ so the product is divisible by $16$. Also, one of $p+1$,$p-1$ is divisible by $3$ and $p^4-1$ is divisible by $5$ by Fermat's little theorem so multiplying these divisors, we have that the original expression is divisible by $240$. I'm not sure whether we can find a larger divisor.

EDIT: In the comments above @DanielFischer points out that we can get an extra factor of $2$. It's likely the answer is $480$.

Comment: One of $p+1$, $p-1$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: Good observation! There's the extra factor of $2$.

Comment: Does anyone see extra factors? Is this a valable proof?

Comment: The gcd of $7^8 -1$ and $11^8 - 1$ is 480, so that's the answer. I just calculated that by computer. You can just about do it by hand if you factor $p^4-1$ as $(p-1)(p^3+p^2+p+1)$. Then the biggest power you've got to calculate is $11^3 = 1331$. I expect there is a more elegant way.

Comment: @TheodoreAlberter As I stated in a comment on the question, factoring the expression for a few small primes rules out other factors.

Comment: @RobArthan a way to derive it from theoretical considerations is along lab's answer. For all the other primes $q$ the Carmichael function does not divide $8$ so there is a class mod $q$ whose order is not a divisor of $8$ and it contains a prime $p$. For this $p$ we have $q \nmid p^8 -1$.

Comment: @quid: thanks. But I meant a more elegant way of calculating the gcd of $7^8 -1$ and $11^8-1$.

Comment: $n=480$ is the largest with $\lambda(n) = 8,\,$ e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1526161/242).